# how to serve images to a single page application with a sinatra API?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I am trying to serve images to my client application with my Sinatra API

when I use this route, it triggers the file download prompt in my browser rather than loading up an image file, how would I go about serving up an image?

```
get '/images/:project/:img' do
  send_file(ProjectPhotos.serve_file(params)) # => triggers a download of file in browser
end
```

Answer (score 0):

need to add `open` from the OpenURI library

```
get '/images/:project/:img' do
  send_file open(ProjectPhotos.serve_file(params), type: 'image/jpeg', disposition: 'inline')
end
```

Comment: I don't think so. Just the type and disposition optionals should do it.

Answer (score 0):

For serving static images you should use the public folder in Sinatra application root. All files in public folder are served by Sinatra web server without any code needed and the public directory omitted from url.

So "public/yourimage.jpg" is available from "www.yoursite.com/yourimage.jpg"

For more info look at Sinatra [documentation](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Static%20Files).